# Jackson mapper throws "conflicting setter definitions" on Samsung SM-T580

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

**Problem:** When converting JSON to an object with Jackson, the following exception is thrown on my Samsung SM-T580 (Android 6.0.1). The exception is not thrown on a OnePlus3 (Android 6.0.1) or ZenPad 8.0 (Android 5), only on the Samsung SM-T580.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "myanmarEncoding": android.graphics.Paint#setMyanmarEncoding(1 params) vs android.graphics.Paint#setMyanmarEncoding(1 params)
           at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

The mapping is performed like the following (Jackson version 2.8.4).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
...
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    myObj = objectMapper.convertValue(document.getProperties(), MyClass.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    return;
}
```

**Approach:** First, I've added `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to `MyClass`. Then, I've attempted to work around the issue by using `@JsonIgnoreType` on the `android.graphics.Paint` class via mix in. 
This was kind of successful because it prevents the first exception.

Unfortunately, another exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "content": android.widget.HoverPopupWindow#setContent(1 params) vs android.widget.HoverPopupWindow#setContent(1 params)
           at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

The method `android.graphics.Paint#setMyanmarEncoding` and the class `android.widget.HoverPopupWindow` seem to be part of the hidden android sources.

What is happening here and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a workaround by excluding the `Paint.class` and ignoring the `setContent` methods from the Android-hidden `HoverPopupWindow.class`. The related method parameters were defined in [HoverPopupWindow.smali](https://github.com/codename13/framework2/blob/master/smali/android/widget/HoverPopupWindow.smali) (GitHub).

This is how the mixins are applied (before using `objectMapper.convertValue`):

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.addMixIn(android.graphics.Paint.class, IgnoreType.class);
objectMapper.addMixIn(Object.class, IgnoreMethods.class);
```

The mixin classes are defined like the following:

```
@JsonIgnoreType
public class IgnoreType {}

interface IgnoreMethods {
    @JsonIgnore
    void setContent(int resId);

    @JsonIgnore
    void setContent(View view);

    @JsonIgnore
    void setContent(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp);

    @JsonIgnore
    void setContent(CharSequence text);
}
```

Unfortunately, I still don't know why the mapper tries to instantiate `Paint` and `HoverPopupView` classes on this specific device.